# Source Of The pci.ids file

Tags: pci, lspci

What is the source of the `pci.ids` file?
Is it part of the `pciutils` package or included when OS is designed without regarding `pciutils` package?

It looks like the file may be located in different directories on different Linux OSes (pci.ids file location is different on Ubuntu and Fedora).

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=pci.ids&mode=exactfilename&suite=hirsute&arch=any

Answer (score 1):

Content comes from a website: https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/ (mirror https://github.com/pciutils/pciids )

> it looks like the file may be located in different directories on different Linux OSes (pci.ids file location is different on Ubuntu and Fedora).

Correct but why does that matter? You use a command/tool to update and probe for vendor ids so the system will find it itself.

- Debian base systems use [pci.ids](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/pci.ids) and `/usr/share/misc/pci.ids`
- Others can also use [hwdata](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/hwdata) and `/usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids`

Comment: I have made a search on ```https://packages.ubuntu.com/``` site which @mook765 wrote in the comments and found the following information: ```pciutils``` package has ```libpci3``` dependency and ```libpci3``` package has ```pci.ids``` dependency. It looks like```pci.ids``` will be installed if ```pciutils``` is installed on Ubuntu if these packages are not present on the system (or removed).